# Reading jQuery JSON Structure - cant get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following JSON structure, being returned from an AJAX call (pseudo values)

```
[
  {
    "id":"14",
    "product_title":"Foo Bar v1.2",
    "discount":"10% Off - New price: $97",
    "vendor":"foobar"
  }
]
```

Here is my AJAX routine.

```
    $.post('Ajax.php',function(res){
        alert(res.product_title);
      });
    },'json');
```

However, the alert says "Undefined", even though it is clearly not (Firebug).

I tried doing a `$.each();` on the res, and it appears the only "key" in there is "0".

What am I doing wrong here? Is it the way I am processing the structure? Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try :

```
var j = res.pop(); // this will extract the `object` form the `array`
console.log(j.product_title);
```

you can also write:

```
res.pop().product_title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Response is returning an array of `object`, so you have to access the first element from the array like this:

```
function(res){
        alert(res[0].product_title);
      }
```