# Multidimensional JSON structure issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following pseudo structure.

```
[
   {"product":
      {
        "id":"14",
        "product_title":"My Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An awesome product.."
      }
   }, 
   {"product":
      {
        "id":"15",
        "product_title":"My MORE Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An AWESOMER product..."
      }
   }
]
```

I am iterating it like this:

```
$.post('Ajax.php',function(res){
  res = res.pop();
  $.each(res,function(product){
    alert(product.product_title);
  });
});
```

However, only the last `product_title` is being shown. It does not go thru all of them.
Is it my code, or my JSON structure? Thanks!

EDIT: reason for the `.pop();`: [Reading jQuery JSON Structure - cant get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149202/reading-jquery-json-structure-cant-get-it-to-work/8149260#8149260)

Comment: why the `.pop()`? it doesn't return the array but whatever is in the last index of the array and removes it from the array

Comment: @Esailija - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149202/reading-jquery-json-structure-cant-get-it-to-work/8149260#8149260 - my previous question :)

Comment: Does that iterate through all the products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to iterate just don't pop...

```
$.post('Ajax.php',function(res){

  $.each(res,function( index, value ){
   alert( value.product.product_title );
  });
});
```

Also, your JSON structure has some redundancy, it could be written as:

```
[
      {
        "id":"14",
        "product_title":"My Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An awesome product.."
      },


      {
        "id":"15",
        "product_title":"My MORE Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An AWESOMER product..."
      }
]
```

Which means an array of products. You always want your arrays to contain things of single type. If you wanted to return multiple things from the server, this would be more appropriate structure:

```
{  
    "products": [
      {
        "id":"14",
        "product_title":"My Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An awesome product.."
      },


      {
        "id":"15",
        "product_title":"My MORE Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An AWESOMER product..."
      }
    ],

    "kittens": [
      {
        "id":"14",
        "name":"kitty"
      },


      {
        "id":"15",
        "name": "kitty"
      }
    ]
}
```

An array of products and an array of kittens, never an array of products AND kittens.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However, isn't `value` supposed to be the current `product` in the `each`?

Comment: your json structure is an array of objects, each of which has a single element `product`. So the `value` (which is set to each element of the res array), is actually an object like: `{"product": {"id": 15, "product_title": "..."}}` Which is why you need to do `value.product`, to get at the `product` element within the object, before you get the `product_title`

Answer (score 3):

Your res = res.pop(); line is setting res to be the last element of the res array. If you remove that line it should work as you expect.

Comment: The reason it was suggested in the other question is because your array had only one element. the $.each will iterate over each element in the array so it won't matter how many are in the array. you don't need the .pop()

Comment: Sorry, slow internet here. I removed the pop, and tried @Esailija's answer - which worked. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$.post('Ajax.php', function(res) {
  for (var i = 0, j = res.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(res[i].product.product_title);
  }
});
```

Try this, it should show 2 product titles. JSON structure is fine.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use simple JavaScript iteration (`for` loop):

```
var temp = 
[
   {"product":
      {
        "id":"14",
        "product_title":"My Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An awesome product.."
      }
   }, 
   {"product":
      {
        "id":"15",
        "product_title":"My MORE Awesome Product!",
        "product_desc":"An AWESOMER product..."
      }
   }
]
for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
{
    console.log(temp[i].product.id);
}
```